# .htaccess error "not allowed here" for all for all instructions

Tags: .htaccess, debian

I am using Debian Lenny and Apache 2. I changed the default `.htaccess` file with:

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig
```

But I always get the error message `not allowed here` when putting any instructions in the  `.htaccess` file.

**EDIT:**

file default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
                #AllowOverride All
                #AllowOverride Indexes AuthConfig Limit FileInfo
                AllowOverride AuthConfig
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

        Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
        <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks 
                AllowOverride None
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess:

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

PHP info:

```
apache2handler

Apache Version = Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny10 with Suhosin-Patch 
Apache API Version = 20051115 
Server Administrator = webmaster@localhost 
Hostname:Port = hw-linux.homework:80 
User/Group = www-data(33)/33 
Max Requests = Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100 
Timeouts = Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 15 
Virtual Server = Yes 
Server Root  = /etc/apache2 
Loaded Modules =

core mod_log_config mod_logio prefork http_core mod_so mod_alias mod_auth_basic
mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user
mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_mime mod_negotiation 
mod_php5 mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_status
```

Comment: Please fix your typo so others don't think that's the reason for your problem. What kind of instructions are you trying to put into the file?

Comment: are the same instructions that come OPENCAR. and then allow only simple rewriting rules and the same happens

Comment: I update the information to my question

Comment: Which line does the "not allowed here" error refer to exactly?

Comment: Pekka is talking about `AllowOverriTe` as the typo, please check it.

Comment: does not work with `AllowOverride All`, do not know why but it only works with `AuthConfig`. All lines, clear and enable any line and the same thing happens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will require a minimum of **AllowOverride Authconfig FileInfo Options** inside your `<Directory>` block to get the `.htaccess` you've posted here to work - `mod_rewrite` will require `FileInfo Options` and your `<FilesMatch>` block requires the `Authconfig`.

Also: your statement "does not work with AllowOverride All" is mistaken.  You cannot specify a MORE permissive environment than `AllowOverride All`.  When in doubt, start with that to make sure the rest of your configuration works, *then* narrow it down more specifically (for security's sake).

Answer (score 1):

This option can be used only inside a `Directory` element. So you have to specify a directory which should be protected.

Comment: yes, I put in the application directory and "/var/www" and same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

**not allowed here** is usually caused by trying to set directives in *.htaccess* file that can only be defined in `httpd.conf`.

First try

```
AllowOverride All
```

In your ower most `<Directory>` tag to your www folder. Now your *.htaccess* can work in its full capacity. If this solves the problem, then you can start focusing on security and decrease the number of allowed directives one-by-one.

Comment: are only rules of rewriting and rewriting module is well loaded,

Comment: I recommend you to try `AllowOverride All` first (and make sure no other `<Directory>` tag is overriding it). See the answer for details.

Comment: does not work with `AllowOverride All`, do not know why but it only works with `AuthConfig`